# Composer autoload file variables are not accessible in other files

Tags: php, variables, composer-php, autoload

I am new to the composer and here is my composer.json file:

```
{
    "name": "asd",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "test",
            "email": "test@me.com"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "vlucas/phpdotenv": "^2.4"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "files": [
            "config/bootstrap.php",
            "lib/app.php"
        ],
        "classmap": [
            "lib/ez_sql/shared/ez_sql_core.php",
            "lib/ez_sql/mysql/ez_sql_mysql.php",
            "lib/smarty/libs/"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\" : "app/",
            "Sys\\": "system/"
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see there is an autoload file `config/bootstrap.php` in which I have few classes instances, and I want to access these in other files. But the problem is I can't access until I don't declare as `GLOBAL` variable. For Example:

*config/bootstrap.php*

```
$obj1 = new obj();
$GLOBALS['obj2'] = new obj2();
```

I can access `$obj2` in other files like in `index.php` but can't use `$obj1`.

Is there any other possible way to use `composer autoload` file variable in other files instead of declaring as `global`?

Comment: Why do you want to use globals after all? That will only cause trouble

Comment: Yeah you are right that I shouldn't use the variable as global, but the problem is I am converting our app into PSR-4 standard using composer, and there are many function and objects in bootstrapper that I have to call from everywhere in the app, so that what I want.

Comment: putting them in a function is still global anyway so whats the difference so long as your only loading that composer install and associated global vars for the function you need them in and not site wide...

Answer (score 2):

Composer does its autoloading within a function (see the require statement in `vendor/composer/autoload_real.php:composerRequireXXX()`). The expected use of this is for files containing just functions and classes, not variables. Because functions and classes are always attached to the global scope, those symbols exist after the getLoader function exits. Variables, however, aren't global scope by default and thus are lost when getLoader returns.

You're right in thinking that you must define those variables as global in order for them to survive Composer's scoped autoloading.

You could change `config/bootstrap.php` in either of these ways to make `$obj1` globally-accessible via Composer's autoload files feature:

```
 $obj1 = new obj();
+$GLOBALS['obj1'] = $obj1;
 $GLOBALS['obj2'] = new obj2();
```

or using the `global` keyword:

```
+global $obj1;
 $obj1 = new obj();
 $GLOBALS['obj2'] = new obj2();
```